# log4net rolling file apender across midnight

Tags: log4net, log4net-appender

I'm tring to set the log names to this pattern:
`ApplicationName.Date.log`

This my config file code:

```xml
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="Client.%date{dd-MM-yyyy}.log" type="log4net.Util.PatternString"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="composite"/>
  <datePattern value="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="50MB"/>
  <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %-2level %logger - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

The problem is that at midnight, the file becomes corrupted like this:

```
Client.13-06-2013.log  
Client.13-06-2013.1.log  
Client.13-06-201313-06-2013.1.log  
Client.13-06-201313-06-2013.2.log  
Client.13-06-201313-06-2013.log
```

What I wanted is:

```
Client.13-06-2013.log
Client.13-06-2013.1.log  
Client.13-06-2013.2.log  
Client.14-06-2013.1.log  
Client.14-06-2013.log
```

Any advice will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figued it out, here the code:

```xml
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="Client.log" type="log4net.Util.PatternString" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="composite" />
  <datePattern value=".dd-MM-yy" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
  <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %-2level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I've removed the `%date` from the `file` property 
and added the `staticLogFileName` property, setting it to `false`.